# How do I fix a new unfinished hollow interior door that got wet and has buckling?

Tags: wood, doors, damage

I bought a new door and on the way home it started pouring rain. One corner of my door got wet and there are bubbles/buckling in one corner.

Do I get the door damp and cut slits in the center of buckles and then add glue and clamp down?

I want to repair it doesn’t get worse.

Comment: A picture or two might help us help you. A visit to the [woodworking.se] sister site may give you some ideas, but odds are good that the door is toast.

Comment: You don't fix it, you replace it.

Comment: JACK is right, but there's a possibility of repair. Proper answers depend on detail, though. Photos are almost a requirement unless you vastly improve your description of the door's construction and the damage.

Answer (score 9):

Most hollow doors are made with fiber board and when they get wet, the fiberboard swells and crumbles. I'd take it back to the store and see if they'll replace it. The cost to them isn't worth an unhappy customer. If they don't, think about buying another door. Any repairs will never look good and it will bug you forever.